# Color histogram for a JPEG/PNG python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am trying to detect the dominant colors in an image by computing a color histogram. Here is the image:

[image]

Here is the code I wrote towards histogram computation:

```
img = Image.open("./color/1.jpg")
width =  img.size[0]
height = img.size[1]
colors = img.getcolors(width*height)
```

The problem is that when I say `print(colors)`, it prints a huge number of  RGB value and their corresponding counts.

`[(588, (255, 255, 255)), (878, (254, 255, 255)), (581, (255, 254, 255)), (209, (254, 254, 255)), (238, (253, 254, 255)), (164, (254, 253, 255)), (380, (253, 253, 255)), (232, (252, 253, 255)), (255, (253, 252, 255)), (16, (252, 252, 255)), (253, (251, 252, 255)), (422, (252, 251, 255)), (14, (251, 251, 255)), (296, (250, 251, 255)), (1515, (251, 250, 255)), (22, (250, 250, 255)), (91, (249, 250, 255)), (2, (247, 250, 255)), (88, (250, 249, 255)), (21, (249, 249, 255)), (1, (246, 249, 255)), (52, (249, 248, 255)), (90, (248, 248, 255)), (5, (245, 248, 255)), (1, (249, 247, 255)), (73, (248, 247, 255)), (245, (247, 247, 255)), (1, (248, 246, 255)), (106, (246, 246, 255)), (3, (242, 246, 255)), (3, (247, 245, 255)), (95, (245, 245, 247)), (39, (244, 245, 247)), (2, (246, 244, 255)),...`

It seems to me that the JPEG compression is the cause but I don't know the exact reason. Can someone please help me to compute the histogram in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The color histogram of a 24 bpp image has up to 16777216 entries (most of which have zero frequency).

I don't think it is a good idea to use that for an image which is essentially grayscale (even quasi-binary).

[image]

---

**Update:**

To find the dominant colors in a color image, you can try the k-means method where k is the number of colors you want to find. There is no need to use an intermediate histogram.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer? Why do I have so many RGB values when there are only two colors in the image?

Comment: @user1274878: your image is not perfectly achromatic, and of course also contains intermediate grays.

Comment: can you please suggest a solution in such a scenario.

Comment: @user1274878: convert to grayscale

Comment: well, other images can have all sorts of colors, so how would converting to grayscale help. the image that i have shown above is just an example.

Comment: @user1274878: bad example then.

Comment: sorry, changed it